# S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden

Tags: django, time, amazon-s3

```
<RequestTime>Mon, 14 Mar 2011 10:09:28 GMT</RequestTime>
<ServerTime>2011-03-14T09:09:29Z</ServerTime></Error>
```

**reason**: The reason of this problem is that Amazon S3 allows only a small time stamp variation up to 15 minutes between the server and its requesting client (user pc). As Amazon is a big backup server of large number of users, security does matter a lot.

**solution**: I installed ntp on my ubuntu machine and try to sync it with s3. But still throwing same error.

How can I solved it.

My project is in **Django**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use [UTC time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) for your requests. From the [AWS docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?S3_Authentication.html):

> **Request Elements**
>
> **Time stamp**—Each request must contain the date and time the request
>   was created, represented as a string
>   in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: Update your date with the following:

```
rdate -s ntp.xs4all.nl
```

substitute with whatever ntp server you require.