# S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I can't upload media files to Amazon S3 using `django-storages` and `boto`, and following [this tutorial](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/). I've also checked these questions:

[boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854095/boto-exception-s3responseerror-s3responseerror-403-forbidden?lq=1)

[Getting boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden when uploading file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594944/getting-boto-exception-s3responseerror-s3responseerror-403-forbidden-when-uplo)

But I am not able to use them successfully. I always get the error: `S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden`

My bucket policy is:

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket name>/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "<arn info>"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket name>",
            "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket name>/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

models.py

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars', null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
@require_POST
@login_required(login_url='/acceso/')
def configuracion_usuario_guardar(request):
    u = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    c = Usuario.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    nombre = request.POST.get('nombre', '')
    apellido = request.POST.get('apellido', '')
    cargo = request.POST.get('cargo', '')
    email = request.POST.get('email', '')
    avatar = request.FILES.get('avatar', '')
    u.first_name = nombre
    u.last_name = apellido
    u.email = email
    u.save()
    c.titulo = cargo
    c.avatar = avatar
    c.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/perfil/')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have your 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID' and 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY' set in the settings file?

Comment: Yes. I'm actually able to do `python manage.py collectstatic` successfully.

Comment: Well, your bucket policy seems correct.

Comment: Regardless of what policy you place on a bucket, if the object in question is not publicly readable itself, you will get a 403 when you access it.  Each object needs to be made publicly readable when it is created.  Or you can update the ACL after it is created.

Comment: @garnaat How do you make an object publicly readable when creating it?

Comment: Well, with boto you would do ``key.set_contents_from_file(fp, policy='public-read')``.  How are you uploading the files to S3?

Comment: I just updated my question to include fragments of `models.py` and `views.py`

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that in my template i was using:

```
{% load static %}
```

when i change to

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
```

I got all working !
Hope i helps others !